# C# WCF object[] member type serialisation

Tags: c#, wcf

What to do to allow communication (WCF) of a class like this one :

```
[DataContract]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

'object' cannot be serialize directly... but how to make it work considering that concrete boxed values can be each either 'int', 'double', 'string', 'DataTime' ?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Answer:** Use concrete serializable types.

**Complex Answer:**

Network transmission of data requires that all the information required to accurately recreate an object on either end of the connection needs to be transmitted in order for the serialization to succeed. This is why concrete, serializable types need to be used.

Comment: There isn't one - it's by design. Think for a minute about *why* - the complexities of trying to determine serializable types from `object` would make the process of transforming any object to a network stream of data and back again would be prohibitively expensive and complex.

Comment: I finally found how to do it... I did not expected that but it works : I will add an answer about it

Comment: Can you confirm that using the "object" type in WCF is bad practice? I am trying to reshape a system that serialises properties using the "object" type all over the place, but I find it horrible as we loose the type safety. Also, does it not come at a cost? It has to be much slower to (de)serialise object instead of generic types, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a simple way to do it.

I knew "KnownType" attribute, but I did not expected it to work in that case as I thought this attribute was to specify the entire member type (i.e "object[]") and not each object value in the array.

But it seems to work very well as the serialization uses the know types for each unknown value.

So, for instance, this is working well :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType( typeof( int ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( double ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( string ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( Sample ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( List<object> ) )]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public object[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

and allows Values[i] to be either int, double, string, Sample itself or any List<> of the previous types.

Before discovering that, I was working on a workaround, which works too, but which is a bit long to code. The principle is to remove the DataMember attribute from the 'Values' member and add another member to code the serialization :

```
[DataContract]
public class Sample
{
    public object[] Values { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] SerializableValues
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return ToBytes( Values );
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        set
        { 
            try
            {
                Values = FromBytes( value );
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Values = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```